# contain() in beforeFind() sometimes causes issue in Cakephp4

Tags: php, slug, cakephp-4.x

I have the following association : `ProductsTable hasMany PhotosTable`.

Furthermore, `ProductsTable` uses `Muffin/SlugBehavior` to build a unique slug.

I need to automatically get `Photos` linked to `Products`  each time I get a Product.

So I use `contain()` in `ProductsTable::beforeFind()` because I want it to be independent of any `Controller`.

Here is my `ProductsTable` :

```php
// ProductsTable
class ProductsTable extends Table
{
   public function initialize(array $config): void
   {
      $this->hasMany('Photos');

      $this->addBehavior('Muffin/Slug.Slug', [
         'displayField' => 'title', // 'title' is the field I want to build a unique slug from.
      ]);
   }

   public function beforeFind(Event $event, Query $query, ArrayObject $options, $primary)
   {
      $query->contain('Photos');
      return $query;
   }
}
```

In most cases it works well, but **an issue happens when I try to create a Product with an already existing title (i.e with a slug that already exists)**.

I have the following `InvalidArgumentException` :
Unable to load Photos association. Ensure foreign key in Products is selected.
The exception is thrown in `Muffin/SlugBehavior::_uniqueSlug()`  at the line `$this->_table->exists($conditions)`.

I don't understand exactly what's the problem...

Could anybody tell me how to fix it ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the issue using `$query->enableAutoFields()` in `beforeFind()`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at what `\Cake\ORM\Table::exists()` does:

```php
public function exists($conditions): bool
{
    return (bool)count(
        $this->find('all')
        ->select(['existing' => 1])
        ->where($conditions)
        ->limit(1)
        ->disableHydration()
        ->toArray()
    );
}
```

As you can see, it's a regular find, so your `beforeFind()` will affect it, and force `contain()` on that query. Now since the query only selects one field, this will cause the error that you're seeing, as loading the associated data happens in a separate query, and therefore requires the foreign key value to be selected (the primary key of the source table), otherwise it's impossible to tell which records belong to each other.

This can be solved in many many different ways. For example you could check whether the foreign key fields will be / are present, and only then contain the association:

```php
public function beforeFind(Event $event, Query $query, ArrayObject $options, $primary)
{
    $select = $query->clause('select');
    
    $autoFields = $select === [] || $query->isAutoFieldsEnabled();

    $foreignKey = (array)$this->Photos->getForeignKey();
    $aliasedForeignKey = (array)$this->Photos->getForeignKey();
    $hasForeignKey = array_intersect($foreignKey, $select) === $foreignKey;

    if (
        $autoFields ||
        $hasForeignKey
    ) {
        return $query->contain('Photos');
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Of course this could still cause problems, it could for example suppress errors when you accidentally not include the foreign keys and actually would like to know.

You could also try to only exclude the `exists()` related query, for example by checking for the exact fields:

```php
public function beforeFind(Event $event, Query $query, ArrayObject $options, $primary)
{
    $select = $query->clause('select')
    $existingFields = ['existing' => 1];

    if ($select !== $existingFields) {
        return $query->contain('Photos');
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Yet another option would be to be explicit about what data you are obtaining. Meaning create table methods or [**finders**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-finder-methods) that return the data that you expect, and use them accordingly. Less magic, less surprises.

```php
public function findWithPhotos(Query $query, array $options)
{
    return $query->contain('Photos');
}
```

```php
$query = $productsTable->find('withPhotos');
```